# python docstrings not working?

Tags: python, windows, docstring

```
def myfunc():
    """ My docstring """
    print "hello"

help(myfunc)
```

I get

```
'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Windows 7 64bit, Python 2.6

Comment: Why you no have [more](http://www.computerhope.com/morehlp.htm)?

Comment: This is not a Python question.  This is simply a Window question.

Comment: Can you specify how you execute your script from the command-line?

Answer (score 3):

[Python's help() function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#help) tries to, in your case, execute the [more](http://www.computerhope.com/morehlp.htm) command. It should look something like this, when more is installed:

```
>>> help(myfunc)
Help on function myfunc in module __main__:

myfunc()
    My docstring
```

But you can also do

```
>>> print myfunc.__doc__
 My docstring
```

to read the docstring.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is not that your Windows OS doesn't have `more` but that Windows 7 UAC (User Access Control) runs your command line window in `user mode` instead of `admin mode.` To solve the problem, run `cmd` as an administrator and then run python from that window. That should take care of it. I am assuming that you have already located the `more` program in `C:\Windows\System32\more.com`